# Swiping 3D Carousel in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a 3D carousel with jQuery and CSS3. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/upEC6/40/) is my code.

If user clicks on the next or previous page, it navigates to next or previous page with an effect.

Now, I want to add swiping support to my code. I know that there are a [bunch of libraries](http://www.queness.com/post/11755/11-multi-touch-and-touch-events-javascript-libraries).

But I don't want to detect just swiping. **User may swipe slowly, and I want carousel to start rotating slowly, just with user's finger (or mouse)**.

I can use a library ([from these libraries](http://www.queness.com/post/11755/11-multi-touch-and-touch-events-javascript-libraries)) for detecting fast swiping, with setting time and distance thresholds, *But How to detect slow swiping, and How to Add that effect to my carousel? (It should look like a physical thing...)*

Comment: My bad for skimming your question too quickly. My apologies. My answer was not a 3D slider. Deleting answer.

Answer (score 1):

Bx slider is a good one to look at with this, if offers a ticker mode with automation etc and has very good API options.