# Transform causes div to go away

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a 3d carousel with CSS3 and jQuery. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/upEC6/45/) is my code.

Currently, my problem is that if I set this line of css code to `main` class, the location, and the zoom of everything will be changed:

```
-webkit-transform: rotateY(20deg) ;
```

My question is, how to rotate the `main` class without any other changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your -1000px margin on .main. If you get rid of it, you can start to apply rotations to that DOM element.

http://jsfiddle.net/upEC6/53/

Try using negative degrees to rotate.

Comment: See this: http://jsfiddle.net/upEC6/48/  I don't think that this is a true rotation of my main div.

Comment: No, that is a true rotation. The elements inside (and possibly .main) are being over-ridden by other scripting and transform rules. http://jsfiddle.net/upEC6/53/ Hard to tell without combing over every line of your code... You might try disabling all other transforms to see if you can get it to rotate.

Comment: Actually, just use negative rotation degrees... seems to be working for me. http://jsfiddle.net/upEC6/54/

Comment: I want `rotateY`. The blue div has the same size as the white one. I just want to rotate my main div, So the blue div (a1) be at the place of the white one, with same size, of course. (I want to do some animations with that) My real problem is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845277/swiping-3d-carousel-in-jquery and I want to make it possible with rotating the main div.

Comment: So you want a pentagonal box that spins with you click or swipe? Something like this, but pentagonal and it only rotates on the y-axis? http://www.paulrhayes.com/experiments/cube-3d/

Comment: It currently rotates when user clicks on the next or previous page. also making it for swiping is also easy. My problem is about **slow swiping**, that pages should rotated *with user's finger.*... So I must rotate my carousel from 1 degrees to 20 degrees.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15032/discussion-between-mahdi-ghiasi-and-matthew-blancarte)

Answer (score 1):

This is a really interesting issue.  I'm using Google Chrome and have not tested in Safari, but it appears that at least Chrome seems to create a new painting stack when -webkit-transform is used.  If you notice, `<div class="main">` no longer has a height.  It's as though the contents of the element have been abstracted from their parent.

In any case, I noticed that it becomes visible again if you give it a static height instead of a percentage (like 500px) and if you remove the negative margin (which doesn't appear to do anything anyway).

Comment: It seems like bigger than my real `div`. see this: http://jsfiddle.net/upEC6/51/  How to avoid that?

Comment: The blue div has the same size as the white one. I just want to rotate my main div, So the blue div (`a1`) be at the place of the white one, with same size, of course. (I want to do some animations with that)

Comment: My real problem is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845277/swiping-3d-carousel-in-jquery  And I want to make it possible with rotating the main div.

Comment: From the current [CSS Transformations](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/) working draft, "any value other than ‘none’ for the transform results in the creation of both a stacking context and a containing block".

Comment: @ephemient I didn't get what you said. Can you explain more?